# Kriging with barriers in R?

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, kriging, barriers

I wonder if there is a way to interpolate xyz points in a raster within certain bounds using R? In ArcGIS this is called interpolation with barriers. I wonder if there is something similar in R? I would like to use the kriging method.

Comment: xyz points? Are your data measurements in three dimensions? Or is it xy position and measurement z?

Comment: In this book there is very nice explanation of how to use R to preform a Kriging, maybe it have the answers you need. [http://spatial-analyst.net/book/](http://spatial-analyst.net/book/)

Comment: Linking related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8676/kriging-with-barriers-in-arcgis-desktop

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `gdistance` package to create a cost surface raster, then use the `shortestPath` function to compute the distances between all your data points. You then need to do your interpolation using that distance matrix as your distance metric and not pythagoras. I think gstat will let you feed in a distance matrix for kriging.

You'll probably also need to use `shortestPath` to compute the distances between your data points and the grid points for your interpolated grid when you come to compute the mean and variance of your kriging estimates over your space.

Assuming this is really two-dimensional...

There was a thread on R-sig-geo in 2010 that is relevant and there was a solution using GRASS to compute the distances and a modified geoR to do the kriging:

http://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-geo@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg06855.html

Comment: +1 This is a clever and powerful method. Note, however, that it differs from kriging with barriers (and will get different results), and so might not be a universal substitute for kriging with barriers. Not only that, you should make sure to estimate the variogram using the same method: applying a variogram derived from Euclidean distances to a different distance function is not valid. Moreover, the algorithm is limited: not only do you need the distance matrix for the data points, you also need all distances between *interpolation* points and data points (that can be a huge number).

Comment: What is kriging with barriers if not what I thought it was?

Comment: What did *you* think it was, precisely? As implemented by the other Spatial Analyst interpolation techniques, interpolation with "barriers" means that one or more polylines are used to *exclude* points from local neighborhood searches. The method you describe here potentially keeps those points within the neighborhoods but extends their distances. That will change the interpolated values.

Comment: Are those points included in any other part of the process? Its not just clipping out points inside the barrier regions?

Comment: It differs from clipping the result *ex post facto*. Consider, *e.g.,* interpolation within a waterbody into which a peninsula juts. If you ignore the land barrier, you might include points on the other side of the peninsula when interpolating. With the land barrier, you cannot use across-peninsula points at all when interpolating. In your approach, the across-peninsula points might be included but are associated with the long distances needed to go around the peninsula. That's three distinct approaches, three distinct results, each appropriate for its own set of applications.

Comment: So the peninsula creates effectively a shadow, and points within that shadow are not used, and those outside it are fully used? That doesn't seem very physically appealing, since you've now got a shadow line across the water that extends away from the peninsula, and the idea that points close to that line would have different roles in the underlying process isn't plausible. Is it as plausible as saying a point 100m measured by going around a peninsula (the gdistance method) is equivalent to a point 100m directly away? At least that is continuous and smooth...

Comment: Well put--but plausibility depends on the application. The three different approaches correspond to three different statistical models of the phenomenon. Each has its place. E.g., barriers are naturally used to interpolate DEMs around cliffs and to interpolate groundwater conditions around stagnant flow areas. In general, all data points are used; the issue is at each given interpolation location, *which* points are used and what weights will they be given?

Comment: True. The real fail here is untrained operators sticking their data into plug-in software without thought to what they are actually doing. Which is what a lot of proprietary statistical solutions advertise.

Answer (score 3):

Soap-film smoothing using GAM's may work for you.

Powerpoint on method
http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~sw283/talks/soap-talk.pdf

R Package download (you will need both the soap and mgcv packages)
http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~sw283/simon/software.html

Comment: not found in 2018

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the [constrainedKriging](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/constrainedKriging/constrainedKriging.pdf) package. According to the description:

> The package supplies functions for two-dimensional spatial
>   interpolation by constrained,covariance-matching constrained and
>   universal (external drift) kriging for points or block of any shape
>   for data with a nonstationary mean function and an isotropic weakly
>   stationary variogram.

Comment: This is an interesting package, but it does not address the question: it has no capability to utilize barriers. One of its abilities is to predict *average values within arbitrary polygons*, but this is not at all the same thing as using barriers to restrict the local neighborhood searches.